Animated film for adults with funny bathroom scene
This was an crudely-ish animated film around the early 90s. Had swearing and adult themes. I remember a tiny red ball that gave the beholder unlimited strength. The bad general of the film had the ball in his neck which gave him power to blow up what he touched. He used a urinal and blew his stuff off. Need help remembering more and identifying.

What you're thinking of is probably Bill Plympton's I married a Strange Person. The hero gets some kind of magical lump on his neck that basically creates what he is thinking of (or something in that line, I saw this a long time ago, my memory may not be perfect). He is ultimately chased by some military people who eventually get ahold of the thing and the scene you described then unfold.
